# Recursion and Pyramids

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a assignment that implements recursion and was having difficulty understanding how to do this with recusion.

I need to be able to detect if the array has multiple columns/rows then compute the weight of each..

here is what it says:

```
The weight supported at each object is the weight of the object itself, plus 
half of the supported weight of the objects above it.

The weight supported by A is the weight of A itself.

The weight supported by B is the weight of B plus 1/2 the weight of A.

The weight supported by C is the weight of C plus 1/2 the weight of A.

The weight supported by E is the weight of E itself, plus 1/2 of the weight         
supported by B and 1/2 of the weight supported by C.
```

Here is what I have so far, I tested if there is only one element and returned it:

```
public static double computePyramidWeights(double [][] weights, int row, int col){
    if (row == 0 && col == 0) {
        return weights[0][0];
    }

    return 1.0; //I know this should be where the recursive goes
}
```

Given ex. like:

```
    A
  B    C
D    E    D
```

Comment: the question would be slightly easier to answer with sample array and input with expected output. otherwise we need to guess about the array's structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This relies on my assumption that the pyramid is structured in the 2D array as {{A},{B,C},{D,E,F}}, which you did not specify.

```
public static double computePyramidWeights(double [][] weights, int row, int col){
    if (row < 0 || col < 0 || col >= weights[row].length) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return weights[row][col]
            + 0.5 * computePyramidWeights(weights, row-1, col)
            + 0.5 * computePyramidWeights(weights, row-1, col-1);
}
```

Note that this function is focused on computing, not on validating input. If the caller of this algorithm requested the weight of a nonexistent row, for example, it might throw an exception. However, throwing an exception is a perfectly reasonable outcome! Why? Because it would indicate a coding error that needs to be fixed, and you should not mask programmer errors unnecessarily.

If, however, you need to validate user input, (e.g. user is inputting column and row) that could (and should) be done with a separate function:

```
// demonstrate how to do a separate input validity check
public static boolean validRowCol(double [][] weights, int row, int col) {
    // return false if there is no such weights[row][col]
    return row >= 0 && col >= 0 && row < weights.length && col < weights[row].length;
}
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So I was wanting to be able to handle basically any case. That makes sense however if it's an improper row it will not catch it. Will go out of bounds.

Comment: So I can create another if statement and test if it's null, or I could test and see if that element is in the array. Which way is perferred? Guessing if it's in the array

Comment: if the user of this algorithm passes in `null` for weights, then throwing an exception is a perfectly reasonable outcome. It would indicate a coding error that needs to be fixed, and you should not mask programmer errors unnecessarily.  If, however, you need to validate user input, (e.g. user is inputting column and row) that could be done with a separate function.

Comment: Ok makes sense. For example, if I did not want new input and just want to return 0.0 can I just call  row >= weights.length;

Comment: I am repeating myself because you asked the same question: if the user of this algorithm requested the weight of a nonexistent row, then throwing an exception is a perfectly reasonable outcome.  It would indicate a coding error that needs to be fixed, and you should not mask programmer errors unnecessarily. If, however, you need to validate user input, (e.g. user is inputting column and row) that could (and should) be done with a separate function.